# Does flock lock the file across processes?

Tags: php, linux, flock

The following code triggers an error, though very rarely, when calling `file_get_contents` that the file does not exist, even though `file_exists` was called only a few statements above.

I believe that the file got deleted, by a cron job, between the time `file_exists` was called the error was triggered.

```
$isRead = self::FILE_READ === $action;
$exists = file_exists($file);
$handle = fopen($file, ($isRead ? 'r' : 'c+'));
if ($handle) {
    $locked = flock($handle, ($isRead ? LOCK_SH : LOCK_EX));
    if ($locked) {
        if ($exists) {
            // Sometimes (very rarely) the following line triggers an error that
            // $file does not exist
            $data = (int)file_get_contents($file);
        } else {
            $data = 0;
        }

        if ($isRead) {
            // Get Counter
            flock($handle, LOCK_UN);

            return $data;
        }

        // Update Counter
        if (self::FILE_UPDATE === $action) {
            $value += $data;
        }
        ftruncate($handle, 0);
        rewind($handle);
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN);

        return true;
    }
    trigger_error("[FileCache] Failed to acquire lock for updating ${file}", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    trigger_error("[FileCache] Failed to open file ${file}", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Does flock in PHP guarantee that the file will not be modified by any other processes? Or is it limited to the current process?

Also, does `unlink` in php honour `flock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux (and other UNIX) systems, `flock()` is purely a advisory lock. It will prevent other processes from obtaining a conflicting lock on the same file with `flock()`, but it will not prevent the file from being modified or removed.

On Windows systems, `flock()` is a mandatory lock, and will prevent modifications to the file.

Comment: Thank you. But my question was about the PHP internals. Does php interpreter honour the lock from another process?

Comment: My answer is about the PHP internals. The only part of PHP that uses `flock()` is `flock()`.